# Openshot .svg titles no longer appear

Tags: arch-linux, openshot

OpenShot in Arch Linux does not seem to allow me to add titles to a project. The titles are created fine (and if you search using a file browser, they appear in the relevant thumbnail folder) but they do not get added to the project (i.e. they won't show in the list of files for the project).

What would be causing this issue and how would I fix it? Or even diagnose what is going on.

I tried this with both old projects (from a Ubuntu 14.04 install) and new projects, with the same issue. Trying to import the .svg files manually using the "Import Files" option results in OpenShot showing an error "OpenShot does not support this file type". Interestingly, it won't allow me to import png images either, and jpg images show up as a white square.

Note: this was working fine in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for some reason, I couldn't open OpenShot at all (got locked). I removed the .openshot folder in my home folder.

And now OpenShot is properly saving titles! I have no idea whether the titles were working before it crashed or only after I removed the .openshot folder, but I thought I would let people know that the issue is no longer there.

I will keep the question without an accepted answer, as I don't remember exactly whether this fixed the issue or whether it just started working by itself.